# Tableview laggy when inserting dynamic cells and scrolling to bottom

Tags: swift, performance, uitableview, smooth-scrolling, reloadrows

I'm making a chatbot app, in which I'm adding different kind of cells in a tableview (with dynamic height), and after adding, I'm scrolling to the bottom.

When the content size of the tableview is smaller compared to the height of the screen, there's no problem with adding the cells. But when the tableview content size has to grow (outside the screen), adding of the cells is laggy, and on my old iPad (iOS 10), cells aren't even displayed right (parts are cut off). Could anyone help me?

I do a network call to get the new message, after I have clicked on a cell option. With the result of that call, I fill the tableview.

```
func ask(sessionId: String, question: String, retry : Bool, completion : @escaping CompletionBlock) {
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: self.defaultHeaders).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let results):
                completion(.success, results as? NSObject)
                break
            case .failure:
                completion(.error, nil)
                break
            }
        }
}
```

When the call was successful, and the dataobject was added to a array with the new message in it, I'm adding the new cell in this part:

```
func insertRowChatView(chatContent: [ChatMessage]) {
    if chatContent.count > self.chatMessageArray.count {
        self.chatMessageArray = chatContent

        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.chatMessageArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And my cellforrowatindexpath code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (chatMessageArray.count) > indexPath.row {
        if chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].dialogOptions != nil && chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].dialogOptions!.count > 0 {
            // Dialogoptions cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatDialogOptionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChatDialogOptionCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setupCell(dialogOptions: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].dialogOptions!, text: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].text!, lastItem: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].lastItem)
            return cell
        } else if chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].links != nil && chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].links!.count > 0 {
            // Links cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatLinkCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChatLinkCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setupCell(links: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].links!, text: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].text!, lastItem: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].lastItem)
            return cell
        } else if chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].text != nil && chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].text != "" {
            // Text only
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatTextOnlyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChatTextOnlyCell
            cell.setupCell(text: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].text!, askedByUser: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].askedByUser, lastItem: chatMessageArray[indexPath.row].lastItem)
            return cell
        } else {
            // Typing indicator
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatTypingIndicatorCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChatTypingIndicatorCell
            cell.setupCell()
            return cell
        }
    }

    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    return cell
}
```

Is there a problem with my code, causing this performance problem?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: when are you call "ask" func? share your "cellforRowAtIndexPath" func codes.

Comment: I call the 'ask' function at the start, and when I am choosing one of the options in the cell (buttons). I send that option to the backend, and getting a result back. After that, I add a new cell with that result. I added the cellforrow function.

Comment: :( add setupCell() source code, please